# Bluetooth doesn't detect IBKS USB beacons when the device locks after some minutes

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using Alt-beacon as the library to manage my IBKS USB beacons. When I start Bluetooth service and I activate the Scan process, beacons are detected and my app works fine. However, after some minutes the device locks and Bluetooth doesn't detect any beacon.

Definition of my BeaconRanging.class:

```
public class BeaconRaging extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {

  private final String TAG = "ALTBEACON";

  private BeaconManager beaconManager;
  private List<String> beaconList;

  private List<String> scannedDevicesList;
  private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

  ListView devicesList;
  ......
```

Method onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate de BeaconRanging");
    this.beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    this.beaconManager.bind(this);
    this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    this.beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
    this.beaconManager.setBackgroundMode(true);
    this.beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2100l);
    this.beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(2900l);
    this.beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(21001);
    this.beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(29001);
    this.beaconList = new ArrayList<>();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "worker");
}
```

Method onDestroy():

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
```

Method onStartCommand():

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Method onBeaconServiceConnect():

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            Log.i("JSON", "Busqueda BLE");
            Log.i("JSON", String.valueOf(beacons.size()));
            beaconList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Beacon beacon: beacons){
                Log.d(TAG, "[BEACON] " + beacon.getIdentifiers().toString() + "; "+ beacon.getDistance());
                beaconList.add(new RawBeacon(beacon.getId1().toString(), beacon.getId2().toInt(), beacon.getId3().toInt(), beacon.getDistance()));
            }
            publishResults();
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region(pam.getUuid(), null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {    }
}
```

This problem appears depending on the mobile device and android version. In my case, I am using "org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.+" as library. Depending on the mobile device, the Bluetooth service stops detecting before.

Comment: Hi Josué, have you implemented all the `AltBeacon` methods inside your `Application` class (which is required for background scanning)? Could you let us see more code? BR,

Comment: Hi margabro! I have added more code and edited my question with all implemented methods. I hope that information could help to identify my problem.

Comment: Sorry, probably it is too late but I post this in case others need it. In the Accent Systems support website you can find a iBKS Hello World app example which includes the background scan. Check it here: https://accent-systems.com/support/developers/ibks-hello-world/